# Adding line breaks to a text/plain email

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer, plaintext

I'm having a problem sending a `plain text` (not `HTML`!) email, all my line breaks are being ignored:

```
->setBody('Did you request a password reset for your account?\r\n\r\nIf yes, click here:\r\nhttp://www.website.com', 'text/plain');
```

The above is being displayed in the email as:

> Did you request a password reset for your account?\r\n\r\nIf yes,
>   click here:\nhttp://www.website.com

I've checked and the header is apparently set correctly:

`Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: @John That is not the right answer in this situation.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are using literal strings. If you would like to add the line breaks, use double quotes instead of a single quote.

```
->setBody("Did you request a password reset for your account?\r\n\r\nIf yes, click here:\r\nhttp://www.website.com", 'text/plain');
```

Comment: Although @silly beat you by a few seconds, you do actually give a reason as to why it wasn't working. I should have marked yours correct to begin with.

Answer (score 62):

use double quotes like this

```
->setBody("Did you request a password reset for your account?\r\n\r\nIf yes, click here:\r\nhttp://www.website.com", 'text/plain');
```