# Making a linebreak in PHP

Tags: php, variables

Im trying to get more variables just in one variable with linebreaks and after that variable is set I want to mail that variable to my mailadres but that is working fine!
My code for now is:

```
$factuur = $bedrijfslogo . '<br>' . $bedrijfsadres . '<br>' . $datum . '<br>'
. $factuurnummer;
```

But this isnt working because in my mail i get `<br>` and not a linebreak.
How do i fix that?

I tried to use `echo <br>` and `echo <br />` but it isnt working. It gives me parse errors or other errors.

Comment: Exactly what error ? edit in question.

Comment: Please post your full code

Comment: If your email isn't an HTML email you have to use `"\n"` to create your linebreaks. If your email is an HTML email you can also use `"<br>\n"`.

Comment: Looks like you need to add HTML headers to your email

Comment: If your headers don't contain the proper syntax to send as HTML, using `<br>` will indeed echo that. Consult the manual => http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 3):

Try using `"\r\n\r\n"` instead `'<br>'`:

```
$factuur = $bedrijfslogo . "\r\n\r\n" . $bedrijfsadres . "\r\n\r\n" . $datum . "\r\n\r\n" . $factuurnummer;
```

If you send the mail without explicitely stating that it contains HTML it will be interpreted as text. For text, a carriage return character \r followed by a newline character \n has to be used.

Since a single "\r\n" (the double quotes " instead of ' is also important here) has to be inserted to break lines in the email's "source code" so that the "source code" lines are not longer than 70 characters, a single "\r\n" is not enough to display a line break to the user. Therefore, two "\r\n" have to be used.

also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9619131/641481

Answer (score 0):

you can use nl2br php function

```
<?php
   echo nl2br("One line.\nAnother line.");
?>
```

you can aslo give line break by

```
<?php
echo "<br />\n";
?>
```

If you want a new line character to be inserted into a plain text stream then you could use the OS independent global `PHP_EOL`

Comment: nl2br() takes a newline (e.g., "\r\n") and replaces it with an HTML <br>, which is the opposite of what the OP wanted.